# Bulk email configuration - phplist + sendgrid or some suggestions on process

Tags: email, bulk, sendgrid

I have a large user list which is distributed in two groups. 1. Phplist 2. Vbulletin

Phplist has around 50,000 users while vbulletin has some 70,000 users. These all are double optin safe lists and completely legal.

We have a dedicated server and use phplist tos end mails but a single mails takes 3 days to process given phplist limitations. I am very keen to use Sendgrid / Amazaon SES or something so that i can shoot pur monthly newsletters much faster ( we have some 20 news letters including jobs, announcements login etc).

At present we send emailes from a different domain than the main one and its like www.mydomainnewsletter.com while main site and corporate emails are www.mydomain.com ( my main site is on drupal)

Now how do I build a process where all transaction and corporate mails go from mydomain.com while all newsletters go from mydomainnewsletters.com. users shall subscribe and unsubscribe at mydomain.com and this email list shall be synchronized with www.mydomainnewsletter.com.

My server has qmail intalled. So can somebody guide me through the process. I am not techie at all.

Comment: just a note: "double opt-in" is spammers' terminology. you may be labeling yourself a spammer by using it.

Comment: oh then what do you say for lists where people are confirmed again using phplist standard process?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, that I can think of. I definitely don't think you should do this in-house unless you want to deal with the huge mess of dealing with deliverability.

Here are some non-in-house options:

1. Build a scheduler, server side, to shoot out the emails to third party providers like [SendGrid](http://www.sendgrid.com/) and [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/), or make bulk email API calls using [PostageApp](http://www.postageapp.com/)
2. Use a service built for newsletters, like [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/), which can manage your lists for you and send out bulk emails without any problems whatsoever.

At least with these services, you're looking at a much faster delivery time. (Three days is attrocious.) They have the resources to send these emails, they worry about the deliverability, and you can focus on making an awesome newsletter and/or working on your website.

**Full Disclosure:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp.